# How to find the longest possible path from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, ecmascript-6

im building an api which needs to find the longest path that matches a number in a very performant manner.

eg

```
// API Request
{
'number': '123456789'
}

// DATA
[
  {
    'prefix': '1',
    'price': 30.5
  },
{
    'prefix': '123',
    'price': 10.5
  },
{
    'prefix': '12345',
    'price': 22.5
  },
]


// API RESPONSE
{
    'prefix': '12345',
    'price': 22.5
  },
```

As you can see from above the response should be the row with prefix of 12345 as it is the longest. please i need a bit of help in doing this. i have spent about 2 days now looking for a solution so i decided to come to stack overflow for answers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share any of your attempts, and explain how they failed or what went wrong?

Comment: `yourData.reduce((longest, current) => { your logic here }, null)`

Comment: What happens if there are two elements with same `prefix` ie, `12345`? If you can mutate the `data` then please try: `data.sort((a, b) => { return a.prefix.length > b.prefix.length ? 1 : -1 })[0];`. It's bit more tricky if you are not allowed to mutate `data`. Please see what this gets you: `const longest = data.find(x => x.prefix.length === Math.max(...data.map(y => y.prefix.length))) ;`. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: @jsN00b i have removed the duplicates from the dataset so it has no duplicates

Comment: @jsN00b that will calculate the max and array of lengths many times.  Better to break it into two tasks: `const max = Math.max(...DATA.map(obj => obj.prefix.length));` then `const result = DATA.find(obj => obj.prefix.length === max);`

Comment: Will your array of DATA include objects with different prefixes that do not match the prefixes of other DATA objects?  e.g.:  `{ "prefix": "9876543", "price": 10 }`  Perhaps your example should more variety of DATA to better illustrate the scope of the problem.  Also, what if there are multiple DATA that have prefixes of the same length, but potentially determine different objects (with potentially different prices).

Comment: The OP is not looking for ... _"the longest possible path from an array of objects"_ ... which hopefully not only to me means a result like ... `'data[2].prefix'` ... for ... **`const incoming = { prefix: '123456789' }`**. The OP's provided `incoming` value even would not match anything due to the `number: '123456789'` key-value pair (btw. `number` being a string type) instead of `prefix: '123456789'` . I highly recommend to edit topic and description of the problem.

Comment: @damiTobiHunjeo ... Regarding the so far provided answers are there any questions left? Are the requirements met?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following where you check each characters position in the prefix to figure out which data set is the best match.

```js
const incoming = {
  'number': '123456789'
}

const data = [{
    'prefix': '1',
    'price': 30.5
  },
  {
    'prefix': '123',
    'price': 10.5
  },
  {
    'prefix': '12345',
    'price': 22.5
  }
];


let bestMatch = {
  matchSuccess: 0,
  data: data[0]
};
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  let matchSuccess = 0;
  for (var x = 0; x < data[i].prefix.length; x++) {
    const c = data[i].prefix.charAt(x);
    if (data[i].prefix.charAt(x) === incoming.number.charAt(x)) {
      matchSuccess++;
    }
  }
  if (matchSuccess > bestMatch.matchSuccess) {
    bestMatch = {
      matchSuccess,
      data: data[i]
    }
  }
}

console.log(bestMatch);
```

Comment: hi thanks for the help. but this solution seems to think that the data can only have numbers associated to the prefix but in reality it can be any mix of numbers eg ``` [{'prefix': '123'}, {'prefix': '3'}, {'prefix': '234'} , {'prefix': '765'},  {'prefix': '12'} , {'prefix': '1'}]``` so ill need to find the longest prefix for '123456' in the mix

Answer (score 0):

From the above comment ...

> *"The OP is not looking for ... *"the longest possible path from an array of objects"* ... which hopefully not only to me means a result like ... `'data[2].prefix'` ... for ... **`const incoming = { prefix: '123456789' }`**. The OP's provided `incoming` value even would not match anything due to the `number: '123456789'` key-value pair (btw. `number` being a string type) instead of `prefix: '123456789'` . I highly recommend to edit topic and description of the problem."*

But what the OP actually might want is ... filter, from an array of objects, the very first object where any of the object entry's stringified values matches the stringified value of the API call in the longest possible way.

```js
function collectItemOfBestCoveringEntryValue(collector, item) {
  const { search = '', coverage = 0, result = null } = collector;
  if (search !== '') {

    const matchingValues = Object
      // retrieve all of an item's values.
      .values(item)
      // filter any value which matches `search`.
      .filter(value => {

        value = String(value);

        return ((
          value !== ''
        ) && (
          // it might even goe both ways ...
          // ... `value` in `search` ...
          search.includes(value) ||
          // ... or `search` in `value`.
          value.includes(search)
        ));
      });

    // retrieve the longest (stringified) value's length.
    const bestCoverage = String(
      matchingValues
        .sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)[0] ?? ''
      ).length;

    if (bestCoverage > coverage) {

      collector.coverage = bestCoverage;
      collector.result = item;
    }
  }
  return collector;
}

const serverSideData = [{
  'prefix': '1',
  'price': 30.5,
}, {
  'prefix': '123',
  'price': 10.5,
}, {
  'prefix': '12345',
  'price': 22.5,
}];

const apiRequest = {
  value: '123456789',
  // or even
  // value: 123456789,
};
const apiResponse = serverSideData
  .reduce(collectItemOfBestCoveringEntryValue, {

    search: String(apiRequest.value),
    result: null,

  }).result;

console.log({ apiResponse });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```